Different readings of 矢筒
I came across the word 矢筒 meaning "quiver" (the bag that you put arrows in). The word was written with the furigana やたて above it. When looking in the dictionary for 矢筒 the only reading I saw was やづつ. However, on typing やたて I also found 矢立て where one of the meanings was also "quiver".
Are both readings correct for 矢筒? Which one is more common?
I also saw 箙{えびら} used to describe 矢筒. How common is this word?

I'm curious — you typed in やたて and your IME gave you the spelling 矢立て. Why would you think this reading also applies to 矢筒?

@EiríkrÚtlendi Not sure I understand your question. The word 矢筒 appeared in the book I'm reading together with the furigana やたて. I typed in やたて and the IME did not give me anything. So I had to type 矢筒 from knowledge of the component kanji, from which I then found the reading  やづつ. Does that make sense?

Ah, thank you for clarifying. I'm under the weather today and this is the third thing where I've misread something. Clearly, I should take the hint and step back from the keyboard until I'm feeling better.


The only reading of 矢筒 I know is やづつ. If it had the furigana やたて, I would probably just think "Oh, yet another creative furigana, or is this a real historical thing, maybe? Well, it doesn't matter". I also know the word 矢入れ (やいれ), but I don't know if there is any difference.
I didn't know the word 箙.

